# What is most GC efficient way to pass a List of items from tree parent to its leaves in Mono 2.6 (.Net 3.5)??

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, mono, unity-game-engine

So we have a tree based on class like this (pseudocode):

```
class TreeItem {
    private TreeItem parent;
    private List<TreeItem> leaves;
   public void Filter(List<Target> targets) { /* filter given list and pass to all leaves */ }
}
```

And this makes GC literaly cry - it accasionally drops in and FPS goes down to 15 and it filters something around 2.5 megs of garbage.

We call that function each frame and this is something we can not avoid. We really do not want to call `GC.collect` each frame/each `N` frames.

List that we pass to children is generated via LINQ expression with `.ToList()` at the end (passing filtered out IEnumerator (meaning link to parts of original collection) makes performance drop even lower).

In our `Filter` function we do not modify given collection - just filter it.

So my question is: how to keep at least same filtering performance and get rid of GC dropping our fps?

Comment: I think the first issue is using Linq in the first place. Linq calls will very, very often instantiate intermediate objects. Do *not* call Linq queries every frame. Linq is about convenience, not performance. In general, try to reduce the per-frame allocation as much as possible. Besides that - can you describe a bit more what you're doing (what is Filter doing exactly), using a bit more code.

Comment: What are the numbers? How long is the list of targets? How big is your list? How much filtering does each node do? (I.e. does it send 95% or 5% of targets down?)

Comment: list of targets from 2 to 30, it sends around 60% of targets down; We are filtering bounding boxes while targets are points.

Comment: Yes, you need to be more specific about the contents of method `Filter` so we can come up with concrete answers.

Comment: Not sure what's going on in Mono these days but this can't be a problem in a generational GC.  Frame data should always be gen# 0 data and not survive long.  A gen# 0 collection doesn't take more than ~100 msec, not long enough to affect FPS.  Do make sure you identified the problem correctly and don't actually have an issue with a gen #2 collection.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say exactly what type of objects take up all that memory, but from your mention of ToList() it sounds like you are creating lots of List instances, and possible intermediary objects within LINQ.

To reduce GC pressure, you need to reduce the amount of allocations. You should not allocate new List instances in each Filter(). Perhaps you should not even use List, but some other data structure that is O(1) for removal. Alternatively, don't remove elements from the list, but just replace  elements that should be removed with some placeholder (null might do).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider processing each target separately:

```
public void Filter(Target target)
```

That way, there is no need to allocate anything. And you're trading calling `MoveNext()` and `Current` lots of times with calling `Filter()` lots of times, so the performance when ignoring the GC may not suffer either. (Though it can, `MoveNext()` and `Current` can be inlined, recursive calls to `Filter()` can't.)